# Buscar registros entre duas datas utilizando o eloquent do laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Preciso buscar registros no banco entre duas datas.

**exemplo:**

```
$emprestimos_material_qtd = MultimeiosDetalheEmprestimo::
      where('recursoId', 2)
       ->where('dataDevolucao', null)
       ->whereDate('dataEmprestimoSaida', '>=', '2019-02-07 16:00:00')
       ->whereDate('dataEmprestimoDevolucao', '<=', '2019-02-14 15:06:00')
       ->get();
```

No banco de dados tenho os seguintes registros

```
(7, 12, 2, 'agendado', '2019-02-07 16:00:00', '2019-02-09 13:00:00', NULL, '10.1.2.113', NULL, 182, NULL, 3, NULL, '2019-02-04 19:04:36', '2019-02-04 19:04:36'),
(10, 13, 2, 'agendado', '2019-02-07 16:00:00', '2019-02-09 13:00:00', NULL, '10.1.2.113', NULL, 182, NULL, 3, NULL, '2019-02-04 19:05:37', '2019-02-04 19:05:37'),
-- (13, 15, 2, 'agendado', '2019-02-13 15:06:00', '2019-02-14 15:06:00', NULL, '10.1.2.113', NULL, 182, NULL, 3, NULL, '2019-02-05 17:15:38', '2019-02-05 17:15:38'),
-- (14, 15, 2, 'agendado', '2019-02-13 15:06:00', '2019-02-14 15:06:00', NULL, '10.1.2.113', NULL, 182, NULL, 3, NULL, '2019-02-05 17:15:38', '2019-02-05 17:15:38'),
```

OBS: A primeira data é o campo dataEmprestimoSaida a segunda dataEmprestimoDevolucao.

No meu entender ele deveria trazer os 4 registros, porém ele traz apenas 2, os primeiros que tem valores igual do campo dataEmprestimoSaida aos da consulta não é retornado.

Os registros em marcados é selecionado , os outros não apesar de atender a regra da igualdade.

Obs: Mesmo caso eu altere a pesquisa para 
$emprestimos_material_qtd = MultimeiosDetalheEmprestimo::
      where('recursoId', 2)
       ->where('dataDevolucao', null)
       ->whereDate('dataEmprestimoSaida', '>=', '2019-02-07 16:00:00')
       ->get();

Continua trazendo apenas os dois últimos registros da tabela

Comment: A condição era pra ver se `dataEmprestimoSaida` é maior que o valor e também `dataEmprestimoDevolucao` menor ou verificar uma condição ou outra ?

Comment: É pra verificar as duas condições, ou seja buscar todos os registro que esteja nesse intervalo

Comment: mas ali não tem um intervalo, a condição (a query diz isso) ele vai retornar todos os registros que forem `'dataEmprestimoSaida', '>=', '2019-02-07 16:00:00'`e que também tenham `'dataEmprestimoDevolucao', '<=', '2019-02-14 15:06:00'`

Comment: O ideal e você montar o sql e ver se responde como deveria, qual e a coluna `dataEmprestimoSaida` e `dataEmprestimoDevolucao`

Comment: A primeira data é a dataEmprestimoSaida  e a segunda data é a dataEmprestimoDevolucao .  Mesmo caso eu deixe apenas a primeira condição que é ->whereDate('dataEmprestimoSaida', '>=', '2019-02-07 16:00:00') ele continuará trazendo apenas os dois ultimos registro, ou seja os que são iguais ela não retorna.

Comment: Vou responder um teste que fiz aqui ve se vai solucionar seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o que eu estava lendo na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) o `WhereDate();` ele só compara datas e não o timestamp, por exemplo seria a mesma coisa que colocar um `where DATE(created_at) >= ....` o ideal seria utilizar apenas o `where` por exemplo no seu caso:

```
$emprestimos_material_qtd = MultimeiosDetalheEmprestimo::
      where('recursoId', 2)
       ->where('dataDevolucao', null)
       ->where('dataEmprestimoSaida', '>=', '2019-02-07 16:00:00')
       ->where('dataEmprestimoDevolucao', '<=', '2019-02-14 15:06:00')
       ->get();
```

Testa ai e veja se vai se comportar corretamente.

Comment: comportou corretamente, funcionando da maneira esperada.